# How to enforce super trait without implementing the functions?

Tags: types, rust

I want to be able to say "this trait is a child of that super trait so it should implement all its functions".

The issue is that `trait X: Y {}` means that `Y` and `X` must be implemented. I just want `X` to be implemented, but making sure all the functions match `Y`.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb3664b0cbab7f41085a2ad06ec70ed3)

```rust
trait GeneralA {
    fn get_x() -> String;
}

// Issue: cannot do `SpecificA : GeneralA` without also implementing GeneralA, but I want to enforce only having specific implementations, no general or default functions are possible.
trait SpecificA {
    fn get_x() -> String;
}

trait SpecificB {
    fn get_x() -> String;
}

struct S1;

impl SpecificA for S1 {
    fn get_x() -> String {
        "SpecificA->get_x".to_string()
    }
}

impl SpecificB for S1 {
    fn get_x() -> String {
        "SpecificB->get_x".to_string()
    }
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(<S1 as SpecificA>::get_x());
    dbg!(<S1 as SpecificB>::get_x());
}
```

What I want to describe in the type system:

- Structs can implement zero or more `SpecificX` traits.
- Structs cannot implement the `GeneralA` trait.
- All `SpecificX` traits should have all functions of `GeneralA` trait.
- When cast to a trait type, the compiler should error if its not implemented for that struct.

The issue is that Rust expects me to implement `GeneralA` AND `SpecificX`.

How can I do this in the type system?

Comment: If the methods of `GeneralA` are the same as `SpecificA` and `SpecificB`, why not just leave them out altogether?

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that nobody is supposed to implement `GeneralA` at all -- it's just a "template" for `SpecificA` and `SpecificB`, which are supposed to be syntactically the same (at least in part) but have no type-level relationship either to each other or to `GeneralA`. Is that accurate?

Comment: @PeterHall because the type signatures of `SpecificA` and `SpecificB` should be the same, but the implementations are different (one parent `General` to many `Specific` children)
@trentcl yes thats right, I want `GeneralA` to be a single point in the code that enforces a common interface for all `SpecificX` children. If it changes all `SpecificX`'s must also change to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "general" version of the trait is not implemented and the "specific" version is, the relationship between them can't be a supertrait relationship. It sounds like what you want instead is a *generic* trait and some marker types to parameterize it with.

```
trait HasX<T> {
    fn get_x() -> String;
}

struct A {}

impl HasX<A> for S1 {
    fn get_x() -> String {
        "SpecificA->get_x".to_string()
    }
}

struct B {}

impl HasX<B> for S1 {
    fn get_x() -> String {
        "SpecificB->get_x".to_string()
    }
}
```

`A` and `B` need not ever be instantiated¹ – they only exist to parameterize `HasX`. (Depending on the nature of your problem, there may already be types that you can use to parameterize `HasX`; in that case, you don't need to create new ones.)

---

¹ Instead of empty `struct`s, you can use empty `enum`s (like `enum A {}`) to enforce they are *never* instantiated, although this sacrifices some of the flexibility they give you.